# Ruby on Rails Rollback on a new thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running into an issue with the following code. For some reason, it will not allow me to modify the state of my progress bar after the **rollback** method. It will simply not do anything. I don't see why. And I can't call **failed! method** within the operation method because it will rollback and change the state of my progress bar.

```
class Importer
  attr_accessor :file

  def initialize(file)
   @file = file
   @pb = ProgressBar.create
   @pb.number_of_rows(file)
  end

  def import(user)
    Thread.new do
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        errs = operation(user)
        Rails.logger.info "HELLO"
        if errs.any?
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
          @pb.failed!
        end
      end
      Rails.logger.info "WORLD"
    end
  end

  def operation(user)
    errs = []
    i = 0
    user.insurances.each do |insurance|
      i = i+1
      if insurance.can_have_plan?
        Plan.create(:insurance => insurance)
        @pb.update_attribute(:current_row, i )
      else
        errs << "#{insurance.id} cant have a plan"
      end
    end
    errs
  end
end
```

When I delete raise, it will work as desired. Also, why it doesn't print HELLO but it only prints WORLD?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. in your code @fb.failed also gets rolled back due to base transaction.

Your code should look like this.

```
def import(user)
    pb_failure = false
    Thread.new do
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        errs = operation(user)
        Rails.logger.info "HELLO"
        if errs.any?
          pb_failure = true
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end
      end
      @pb.failed! if pb_failure
      Rails.logger.info "WORLD"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Well, it prints "WORLD" into log file. Also, according to ruby on rails doc, it should reach anything underneath it http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html

Comment: Also, if I move @pb.failed! before rollback, it will simply rollback and @pb will still be successful.

Comment: thanks for a suggestion but i have already tried that and it didn't work. basically, when i call raise, it will not execute code bellow it. I am running Rails 3.2.22